# How correct link program with libperl.so

Tags: c, perl

How correct linking with libperl.so

I use Fedora Core 16 and try to compile program with embedding perl follows way:

```
gcc -W -Wall -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/lib/include -I/usr/lib/perl5/CORE -c program.c
gcc -L/lib -L/usr/lib/perl5/CORE -lperl -o program.run program.o
```

After trying to run program I getting following message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

if execute following command 'ldd program.run' then it output to console

```
ldd ./program.run 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7751000)
    libperl.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x4eea5000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x4ee80000)
```

Yes i can set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable and program will be work, but if i execute same command for '/usr/bin/perl' library will be found without setting specific environment variable e.g

```
ldd `which perl`
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77f4000)
    libperl.so => /usr/lib/perl5/CORE/libperl.so (0xb767b000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x4f22f000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x42eaf000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x4f055000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x4f085000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x41ee6000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0x42ecc000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x4f05c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x4eea5000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x4ee80000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib/libfreebl3.so (0x42492000)
```

How correct link program with libperl.so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/perl5/CORE` (when linking) should help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime for the dynamic linker to find `libperl`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/perl5/CORE ./program
```